# Different google maps markers if custom field is empty Wordpress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

I am trying to get different markers on Google Maps for different Categories in WordPress. I can able to get all the markers on the map, but cannot able to achieve it. Hoping to get a solution from here. Thanks for all your help.

What I want exactly is, I want to show Blue color Google marker if custom field is empty, and I want to show Green color if custom field is not empty.

This is my Custom field, $order_online_link = rwmb_meta( 'mt_order' );

Here is all my code,

```
<!-- Content -->
<div id="content">

    <?php
    // if (!empty($location)):
    ?>

    <div class="whole-area">
        <div id="map_wrapper" class="col-sm-10 map-mainportion">
             <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs mapreset" onclick="mapCentered()"><i class="f fa-reload"></i> Reset</button>
            <div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 map-sidebar">

            <!-- Start For Category and Sub Category List  -->
            <?php
            $term_args = array(
                'exclude' => array(251,252,253,254,255,257,258,259,260,261,262,267,295,298,263,264,265),
            );
            $city_group_terms = get_terms('category', $term_args);
            $cp=0;
            foreach ($city_group_terms as $city_group_term) {
                $city_group_query = new WP_Query(array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => array( 'title' => 'ASC'),
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => array($city_group_term->slug),
                            'operator' => 'IN'
                        )
                    )
                ));
                ?>
                <button class="accordion city-based"><span class="city-title"><?php echo $city_group_term->name; ?></span></button>
                <ul class="panel">
                    <?php

                    if ($city_group_query->have_posts()) : while ($city_group_query->have_posts()) : $city_group_query->the_post(); ?>
                            <?php 
                             $loc_title = get_the_title();
                            $location = get_field('google_map_lat_long'); 
                            $order_online_link = rwmb_meta( 'mt_order' );
                            if($order_online_link =='' || $order_online_link =='#'):
                                $mapicon= get_template_directory_uri().'/images/red-icon.png';
                            else:    
                                $mapicon= get_template_directory_uri().'/images/blue-icon.png';
                            endif;

                            $sl_select_obj[] = array("lat" => $location['lat'],
                                    "long" => $location['lng'],
                                    "address" => $loc_title,
                                    "orderlinky" => $order_online_link,
                                    "mapicon"=>$mapicon
                                );
                            //$mpins[]=$cp;
                            $add_site = get_field('company_website');

                            $loc_permalink = get_permalink();
                            $order_online_link = rwmb_meta( 'mt_order' );
                            $locations_data[] = array("site" => $add_site, "loctitle" => $loc_title, "locpermalink" => $loc_permalink, "orderonlinelink" => $order_online_link);
                            ?>
                            <li class="map-list-titles"><a href="javascript:ZoomAndCenter(<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>, <?php echo $location['lng'];?>, <?php echo $cp ?>)" ><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></li>
                                <?php
                                $cp++;
                            endwhile;
                        endif;
                        ?>
                </ul>
                <?php
                // Reset things, for good measure
                $city_group_query = null;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            }
            ?>

            <!-- End For Category and Sub Category List  -->


        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    //endif;
    ?>    

</div>
```

Here is my javascript,

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA157quXbUlHHgm4wJJxzD49MivKgPSil8&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});
var map;
var gmarkers=[];
function initialize() {
    locations = <?php echo json_encode($sl_select_obj) ?>;
    markerdata = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($locations_data) ?>');


   // var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        //center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5287718, -0.2416803),
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };


    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    // Multiple Markers''
    // $info='';
    var markers = locations;


<?php
$total = count($locations_data);
$markerinfo = '';
$c = 0;
foreach ($locations_data as $key => $info):
if ($c != $total):
    $markerinfo .="['<div class=\"info_content\"><h2>" . $info['loctitle'] . "</h2><h3><a href=" . $info['site'] . ">" . $info['site'] . "</a></h3><h4><a  href=" . $info['orderonlinelink'] . ">Order Online</a></h4><h4><a href=" . $info['locpermalink'] . ">View Full Office Details</a></h4></div>'],";
else:
    $markerinfo .="['<div class=\"info_content\"><h2>" . $info['loctitle'] . "</h2><h3><a href=" . $info['site'] . ">" . $info['site'] . "</a></h3><h4><a href=" . $info['locpermalink'] . ">View Full Office Details</a></h4></div>']";
endif;
$c++;
endforeach;
?>



    // Info Window Content                        
    var infoWindowContent = [<?php echo $markerinfo; ?>]; //markerdata; 



    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i]["lat"], markers[i]["long"]);
        var map_center_position = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0059657 ,-118.4440441);
        bounds.extend(map_center_position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i]["address"],
            icon: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/venue-direct-icon.png'
        });
        gmarkers.push(marker);
        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function () {
        infoWindow.close();
        }); 
        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
        this.setZoom(10);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });
  //  map.fitBounds(markerBounds);

}

function ZoomAndCenter(lat,long,markerid) {
   // map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long));
    //map.setZoom(13);
    var latLng=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    map.panTo(latLng);
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[markerid],'click');
}
function mapCentered()
{
     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(34.0059657 ,-118.4440441));
    map.setZoom(10);
}
//Accordationscript
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way how i pushing markers to map, with custom images.

```
var myIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(IMAGE_URL, null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(WIDTH,HEIGHT));

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(LAT, LAN),
     map: MAP,
     icon: myIcon
});
```

In detail https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

basically you cant replace

```
icon: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/venue-direct-icon.png'
```

with  `icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/venue-direct-icon.png', null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(WIDTH,HEIGHT))`

Don't forget add WIDTH and HEIGHT.

Answer (score 0):

I can able to solve the it with the help of a friend. For those who are still wondering can check this, I am passing the Icons through json.encode

And calling the icon in the marker like this, 
    icon: markers[i]["mapicon"]